# Django cms Template for loop breaks itself during rendering

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates, django-cms

ive written an simple plugin but it changes the tree, so that the .container moves after the .head, if it trys to render this part:

```
<a class="head" href="#">
    <div class="container">
        {% for subchild in child.children %}
            <a>{{ subchild }}</a>
        {% empty %}
            notext
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</a>
```

but if i change the outter a tag to anything else it works

Comment: What breaks? Are you specifying this template as part of a menu tag?

Comment: thx 4 ur reply , ive clarified more exactly whats happening, oh and its either rendered as plugin template or as an page template , without difference